# cocos2d and cocosbuilder landscape orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

im having a problem with the landscape rotation while im working with cocos2d and cocosbuilder.

I have **iPhone Landscape** and **iPhone5 Landscape** on my cocosbuilder project 
And on the xcode **Suported Interface Orientations** i only have the landscape selected.

on my appDelegate.m i have:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

this should be really simple, but im having a hard time here, and really don't want to re-assemble my game again without using cocosbuilder

Comment: what version of ios you are using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of both ios / xcode and cocos

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting latest versions of iOS which is mostly used these days, then you should use these methods to check for orientation

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}


-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {


        return YES;    
}
```

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in iOS6 and instead of using this method use the above methods which I have provided and read the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs provided by apple there it is clearly written which methods you could use and for what purpose. here are some of the methods which you might use

```
willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: 
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

Comment: You think it may be a bug on cocosbuilder? because none of that worked

Comment: you are using iOS6 so the methods which are deprecated will not work in your application, check my update in answer

Comment: it doesn't work.. what bothers me is that it works if im not using cocosbuilder, but if i use a ccbi it doesnt work.

Comment: I have not used cocosbuilder but functionality for the viewcontrollers is generic, should work, try to put the break-pointers or NSLog in your methods and see if they are called or not.

Comment: will do, thank you for your help, i´ve also noticed that the default project where it works it has a -Landscape suffix.